# Why do we have to re-enter authentication master password in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, authentication, password

In our companies IT infrastructure (MS Windows 10) we use QGIS authentication configurations for access to PostGIS databases, with the master password opted to be stored in the password manager in order to not having to enter the master passwort each time QGIS starts. That works fine.

If a user works on another PC (e.g. in a training room, desk sharing, or whatsoever), **(s)he has to re-enter the master password**. **Why is this?**

In the docs (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_overview.html#master-password) we can read *"...You can choose to save the password in the Wallet/Keyring of your computer...."*, thus I guess that the master password is not in the authentication database in the server-side profile (`C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\qgis-auth.db`).

Search for e.g. 'Keyring Wallet Windows' did not reveal anything useful.